# Extracting a string from a sentence

Tags: string, perl, extract

I have a file that looks like this

```
the vote will take place tomorrow at card (0.046786214525982)
vote will take place tomorrow at card noon (0.027725129127836) 
vote will take place tomorrow at card am (0.024548598987843)
```

And I want to extract only this part of each line

```
the vote will take place tomorrow at card
vote will take place tomorrow at card noon
vote will take place tomorrow at card am
```

My Perl script is this

```
 perl -ne 'print [split /(/]->[0]' 8-8TRI.txt
```

But it does not work

It says

```
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/( <-- HERE / at -e line 1.
```

Comment: The `(` is a special char within a regexp. Mask it with a backslash `\(`.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ne 'print [ split /\(/ ]->[0]' 8-8TRI.txt
                         ^__ backslash for '('
```

You don't need array reference, so

```
perl -ne 'print( (split /\(/ )[0] )' 8-8TRI.txt
```

Comment: The simplest way is perhaps to use a regex `perl -ne 'print /([^(]+)/'`

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression in `split /(/` is invalid because `(` is a special metacharacter inside a regex and needs a corresponding closing `)` to go with it.

You could escape your opening parenthesis with a backslash `\(` but the shell will also eat backslashes if you use a one-line command, so it is clearer to use a character class `[(]`.

Like this

```
perl -l -pe "s/[(].+//" myfile
```

This uses a substitution `s///` to remove the first open parenthesis and everything after it in each line.

Note that it won't remove any spaces or tabs before the open parenthesis, so the **output** will contain invisible trailing space characters

```
the vote will take place tomorrow at card 
vote will take place tomorrow at card noon 
vote will take place tomorrow at card am
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use perl like this:

```
perl -pe 's/^([^(]*).*$/\1/' file
the vote will take place tomorrow at card 
vote will take place tomorrow at card noon 
vote will take place tomorrow at card am
```

Comment: A character class help get around shell special characters, but an explanation would be useful here.

Comment: It just captures everything before first `(` into `group 1` and substitutes the input with that captured string.